# How do I launch an iOS app upon startup?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4, jailbreak

I am working on a project where the iPad will be used for a specific purpose, and only run one app. When the device starts up, I want my app to run, and I want to override the home button so that it does not quit the app (like the iPhone/ iPod demos in the store).

I have seen bits and pieces of this functionality, but am unsure how to implement it. I realize that it would have to be on a jailbroken device, and the client is fine with that.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Thomas

Edit 1: I found [this site](http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=224341), which explains some iOS daemons. I'm still researching, so I'll just keep posting what I find.

Edit 2: I found Saurik's IRC channel and asked around in there. One of the participants told me that it is possible, but probably not as simple as I thought. I am still doing some digging around in the iPhone 3G filesystem now just to get the feel of what certain things do.

The project has been scrapped, but I'm still looking for help on this though....just cuz I'm interested lol.

Comment: Your tags indicate it, but you should reiterate in the body that you understand this would be for a jailbroken phone only.

Comment: Thanks! I added the line saying that.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://tomstechjournal.blogspot.com/2010/06/research-how-to-launch-ios-app-upon.html) my progress on the issue. Question's still not completely answered, but I'm making some headway :-)

I've been [researching Jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668867/what-does-jailbreak-do-to-the-iphone-technically) and the iOS filesystem as well. That has helped my understanding of the issue some.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do it?

Comment: Nope. I actually haven't looked into it anymore since then lol.

Answer (score 0):

Without jailbreaking this would not be possible.

Comment: Right. Jailbreaking is not a problem. Please let me know if you have any insight on the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be something in /etc somewhere that runs through all the things that start up, just like on Linux.
It so happens that my current ipod touch has a WALD screen after me manually deleting a few mp3 files. Some anti mp3 mocking code policing it, and not liking me touching the mp3 file structures... otherwise I'd look for you right now.

Do you know how to ssh into your ipod/iphone?

Comment: Yep, I'm actually mapping the entire filesystem (documenting where files are stored, what they do, contents, etc) just because I haven't seen anything like that before...think it'd be useful to have lol.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe Apple itself uses this on the iPads running at the Apple Stores (those showing animations about the products where you can ask to talk with a blue shirt).

I would look for something on the official IPCU (iPhone Configuration Utility) to check if there is an option for auto-loading apps on boot time.

If not, try to get friends with someone working on an Apple Store and get some hints on how they run their app on those iPads.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the "voip" key in the information plist.
This is backed up by Apple:
[image]

You can also see this sample project:
https://github.com/lithium3141/BootLaunch

PB.

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work on iOS 6.1. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9300992/1772214