# Restrict my iOS device to a particular app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, security

I'm searching a way to restrict my iOS device to a particular app.

I have found a good way to disable my iPad Home button functionality through [**Kiosk Mode for iOS**](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/02/kiosk-mode-for-ios/)

So is it possible to restrict my iOS device to a particular app without jail-breaking?

Will App-Store reject my application if I done this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can iPhone apps start on start-up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300815/can-iphone-apps-start-on-start-up)

Comment: If it's an Enterprise App, then you aren't going to be putting it on the app store, so it doesn't matter whether or not Apple will reject it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phew... Finally I found.[**Guided Access**](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509)  is a new feature in iOS 6 that will do the functionality .It's a built-in feature.

Guided Access is activated for a particular app, iOS device will automatically launch that app every time.

You can power off the device by holding down the "Power + Home" button.

If you’d like to learn how to use Guided Access in iOS 6, You can see more details [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509)

[image]

Comment: If the device is to be used in a public environment, you can purchase a container that covers the home button -> low-fi and nicely effective, in combination with the above.

Answer (score 1):

That is a huge security violation as far as the App Store would be concerned. For an enterprise applications its possible you could find a way. But for a public App Store download this is not only next to impossible its also a guaranteed rejection.

Comment: what about enterprise applications ? if possible, then tell me the way

Comment: I've never built an enterprise application but once you get the enterprise license you are given a bit more freedom. Basically in an enterprise app you may be allowed to do this but that still doesn't solve the problem that there isn't a public API to do this in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible automatically launch my app every time after iPad booted without jail-breaking?

No. Jailbreaking only will allow you to mess with the default behavior of the system such as Launch Items

> Will Apple-Store reject my application if I implement the behavior?

If you somehow find a way to circumvent the issue, (i.e. exploit a security breach) then your app **will** be rejected.
[App review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), section 2.4, 2.5