# App call guide access

Tags: ios

I want to call guide access so that user only use my app. Please give me some information(links) about this function if you have experience.

I searched on www, while looks like there are some issues. Please help.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is "call guide access" ?

Comment: May be you can check a similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488537/how-can-i-programatically-enable-guided-access-kiosk-mode-on-an-iphone

Comment: sorry, I mean enable guide access programatically.

Answer (score 0):

According to my researching, I need to use 
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession.

While I still have questions (created other thread).