# Unable to install a configuration profile for guided access from Apple Configurator 2

Tags: ios, iphone, accessibility, mdm, guided-access

I am trying to install a mobileconfig file to enable guided access mode programmatically from my application. 
I have created the profile using Apple configurator 2 by adding the key "autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs" manually.

```
<key>autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.apple.ist.GuidedAccessTest</string>
            </array>
```

However when I try to install this profile I get an error saying "Profile Failed to Install [MCInstallationErrorDomain – 0xFA1 (4001)]".

Replacing "autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs" with any other keys such as "blacklistedAppBundleIDs" or "whitelistedAppBundleIDs" which are also an array of strings in restrictions payload works just fine and I could install the profile.

Any pointers as to what I'm missing here? Much appreciated if anyone can point me to a sample mobileconfig file for enabling guided access.

Comment: This might not fix your error, but if you want to turn on Single App Mode programmatically then the profile must be distributed through MDM and the device must be supervised. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27560356/1873374).

Comment: I do have the device supervised. I have created the MDM profile using apple configurator 2. But as mentioned above, it doesn't allow me to install the profile if I add the key "autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs".

Comment: Such a profile can't be installed through Configurator. The profile has to be pushed through your MDM server.