# How can I programmatically disable single app mode?

Tags: ios, swift, mdm

I am using SimpleMDM to handle enable and disable single app mode for my application. App has a "unlockDevice" button. Once single app mode is enabled from MDM and the app has entered single app mode on iPad, app should exit single app mode on this unlockDevice button tap.

```
@IBAction func unlockDevice(_ sender: Any) {
        UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(false, { (didSucceed) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                if didSucceed == true {
                    let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Success", message: "Exited the Single App Mode", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(okAction)
                    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Failure", message: "Failed to exit Single App Mode. Please try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(okAction)
                    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

I have passed false to UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession but the app is not exiting from single app mode. How can I exit the single app mode?

Comment: Does it stay in single app mode _and_ succeed, or does the "Failure" alert show?

Comment: The failure alert comes up and it stays in single app mode.

Comment: Does the configuration profile include your app's bundle ID in the list of applications that can request (and release) guided access mode?  The key is `autonomousSIngleAppModePermittedAppIDs`, [and more information can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27560356/981049).