# Run app when iPhone restart?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4.5, apple-maps

I want to develop an app which will fetch user coordinates and will send it over network to server. App should be run in background as well as if my phone is switched off and restart then app should start the service automatically again.

In Android this is possible. Is this possible in iOS?

Comment: Seems like you can apps that Launch on Boot have a look at this [Post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300815/can-iphone-apps-start-on-start-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so you can get your app working on iphone restart. 
There may be some root level access to do so.
An apple developer can tell u best.