# Reconnect peripheral after reboot - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

So what I'm trying to do is after I connect to a peripheral, I reboot my iPhone, but never close out the app. When the phone boots back up, I'd like the peripheral to reconnect with my app without bringing the app back to the foreground.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without GuidedAccess or jailbreaking your phone, you can't run an app when the phone starts. You'd need to do that in order to reconnect your app to the peripheral.

See: [Make iOS application run at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864999/make-ios-application-run-at-startup)