# iOS app auto-start

Tags: ios, iphone, app-startup

I am working on a VOIP app and need it to auto-start when the iPhone starts up. Everything works 80% of the time. But 20% of the time the app fails to startup. One test scenario is the following:

1. Open app and type something and save
2. Reboot phone
3. Check if app is running by double-tapping the home button but DO NOT open the app.
4. If app is running, reboot phone again and see if the app comes up again in the background process.

This scenarios works most of the time but not always. Other scenarios also fail at times. Can someone clarify if there is a fool-proof way to start a VOIP iOS app every time the phone boots up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't be done.  If a user force quits an app, it stays force quit. That's how apple want it, and that's how it's going to be.  You can't circumvent the users wishes with multitasking.  Also, it's worth knowing that what you see in the fast switcher is not necessarily everything that is running, it's what ios thinks the user should expect to be running ie it may shut something down in the background of its own accord in order to free up resources, but because the user did not initiate it this app will appear to still be open in the switcher, despite that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't open an app on startup. You should include a reminder on the app's first start up for the user to keep that app open in the background.

Comment: Actually, it looks like VOIP apps that run in the background will start when your phone starts.  (Or, judging by the question, it will most of the time): http://stackoverflow.com/a/9300992/1035398