# Launch an app when iPhone turns on

Tags: iphone, launch

I'm making an app that needs to be launched when the user turns on the Iphone. 
How can I make this? It is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300815/can-iphone-apps-start-on-start-up - In short, No.

Answer (score 0):

On a non jailbroken iPhone or iOS Device this is not possible through restriction of iOS/Apple.

If you aim for deploying your app on jailbroken devices have a look at [launchd](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Launchctl).